# Error 0x84b10001 when installing SQL Server 2012 on a machine with VS2013

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm trying to install [SQL Server Express with Service Pack 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/hh230763.aspx) on my Win8 Pro (x64) development machine and I'm consistently getting an error 0x84b10001 when trying to install it:

[image: error message]

Antivirus is disabled during the installation (done as Administrator) and I tried 2 versions of the SQL Server Express package and I'm getting the same issue with both.
I'm getting the same issue whether I'm trying the x86 or x64 packages.

I suspect that the issue comes from the fact that Visual Studio 2013 has already installed some SQL Server packages but I do not see any way to update and modify these to add the Management Studio for istance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, turns out that this cryptic error is due to an [older instance of *SQL Server Desktop Engine* (MSDE) being present](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/747196/setup-fails-with-hexadecimal-value-0x00-is-an-invalid-character-line-1-position-367455).

After uninstalling MSDE, the SQL Server 2012 setup worked without errors.

Comment: Solved the issue for me :)

Answer (score 5):

Create a new local user with administative rights and try the installation again. In my case it solves the problem with MSSQL 2008R2.

Answer (score 2):

Create new user with administrative privileges and install using that user. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Remove folder:
C:\Users[USER ID]\AppData\Local\Microsoft_Corporation

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to install SQL Server 2014 and get this error, use this web site:

http://anewdomain.net/2013/10/21/how-to-enable-net-framework-2-0-and-3-5-in-windows-8-1-for-older-programs/

You should install .NET Framework 2.0 and 3.5 first. You should check the framework versions on your PC. If you have only 4.5, you will continue to get the same error code.

Anyway, I fixed my trouble.

I hope it helps you too.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because trying to install an x86 package on an x64 windows, installing x64 package worked for me.