# SQL Server Setup failure 2008 Error code 0X84B10001

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to install SQL Server 2008 Express and I got the following error code:

> SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:
>   File "C\users\debian\appdata\local\temp\vsrpqs--.dll"not found.
>   Error code 0X84B10001

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled antivirus Avast-it helped

Answer (score 0):

It looks like intallation was interrupted. Try to rollback all changes made (uninstall, delete, etc). Restart your computer and try to install again.

Comment: I restarted my computer and tried to install again-did not help

Comment: Did you uninstall all changes made? It seems like there are some leftover files present in your Windows profile.

Comment: I did not understand.When i first installed Sql Server Express 2008- did  some files of Sql Server  remained ?

Comment: It is for you to find out. Check in Installed programs (Control Panel). Also check for earlier versions of SQL Server Installed. See similar issues http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21643363/error-0x84b10001-when-installing-sql-server-2012-on-a-machine-with-vs2013