# error 0x84b1001 sql install

Tags: sql-server, installation, failed-installation

i've one sql instance installed on the server 2008R2 SP2 X64BIT
and while trying to another , i'm getting the below error:0X84B1001
below log file , pls help!!!!

overall summary:

```
  Final result:                  Failed: see details below
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2068774911
  Exit facility code:            1201
  Exit error code:               1
  Exit message:                  '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 189072.
  Start time:                    2017-08-16 08:37:23
  End time:                      2017-08-16 08:38:45
  Requested action:              Install
  Exception help link:           http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.2000.8&EvtType=0x066FCAFD%400x5539C151&EvtType=0x066FCAFD%400x5539C151
```

User Input Settings:

```
  ACTION:                        Install
  ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      false
  AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  AGTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Manual
  ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup
  ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
  ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config

  ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp

SQLCOLLATION:                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 empty
  SQLSVCPASSWORD:                empty
  SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
  SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           empty
  SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  empty
  SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               empty
  SQLUSERDBDIR:                  empty
  SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               empty
  SQMREPORTING:                  false
  TCPENABLED:                    0
  UIMODE:                        Normal
  UpdateEnabled:                 true
  UpdateSource:                  MU
  USEMICROSOFTUPDATE:            false
  X86:                           false
```

Comment: see this https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/747196/setup-fails-with-hexadecimal-value-0x00-is-an-invalid-character-line-1-position-367455

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error 0x84b10001 when installing SQL Server 2012 on a machine with VS2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21643363/error-0x84b10001-when-installing-sql-server-2012-on-a-machine-with-vs2013)